# Cypress Iframe Handling - Failure to interact with Button

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to E2E test an auth flow with Cypress that includes a third party method called [BankID](https://www.bankid.no/privat/los-mitt-bankid-problem/test-din-bankid---autentisering/). BankId is integrated through three nested iframes that I can successfully access. However, when I type into the input field via cy.type('12345678912'), BankId does not register this as trusted events and never unlocks the submit button with the arrow.

According to this issue [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/311#issuecomment-787508664), Cypress does not intend to support native browser events and suggests to use the package [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events). When using this via `cy.realType('12345678912')`, it actually succeeds in unlocking the submit button. However i can never successfully click the submit button, neither with `.click()` or even the package method `.realClick()`.

The error is: `"Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."`

I uploaded a sample repository with an minimal testing version [here](https://github.com/maltewirz/cypress-iframes).

Any feedback or hints would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is the relevant code:

```
   
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import { skipOn } from '@cypress/skip-test'

describe('Recipe: blogs__iframes', () => {
  skipOn('firefox', () => {
    it('do it more generically', () => {
      const getIframeBody = (identifier) => {
        return cy
        .get(identifier)
        .its('0.contentDocument.body')
        .should('not.be.empty')
        .then(cy.wrap)
      }

      // Visiting the page index.html and getting iframe A
      cy.visit('index.html').contains('XHR in iframe')
      getIframeBody('iframe[data-cy="bankid"]').as('iframeA')

      cy.get('@iframeA').within(() => {
        getIframeBody('iframe[src="https://tools.bankid.no/bankid-test/auth"]').as('iframeB')

        cy.get('@iframeB').within(() => {
          getIframeBody('iframe[src^="https://csfe.bankid.no/CentralServerFEJS"]').as('iframeC')

          // Now we are in the right place and it finds the correct input element.
          // However, normal cypress command .type() fails and we have to use library cypress-real-events,
          // which provides an event firing system that works literally like in puppeteer
          cy.get('@iframeC').find('input[type="tel"]').should('be.visible').realType('12345678912')

          // But for the button below, this library now doesn't help anymore:
          // "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."
          cy.get('@iframeC').find('button[type="submit"]').should('be.visible').first().realClick()
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this problem on https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/issues/226 and got an answer there:

Using `.realClick({ scrollBehavior: false });` solved the issue.

The problem is if the webapp is not scrolling as expected, therefore leading to Cypress not finding the element. In my case, i made the iframe wider to avoid needing to scroll and the issue was still there, but the workaround solved it anyway.