# How to handle iframe in cypress

Tags: iframe, cypress

I recently started to learn cypress.

I am trying to go to this step but I can t click on that button because it is in an iframe
-Go to this URL https://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/alert.php#load_box
-Click "Input alert"
-Click "Click the button to demonstrate the input box"

If I run this I get an error
`Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.its() errored because the property: 0.contentDocument.body does not exist on your subject.` cy.its()`waited for the specified property 0.contentDocument.body to exist, but it never did. If you do not expect the property 0.contentDocument.body to exist, then add an assertion such as:`cy.wrap({ foo: 'bar' }).its('quux').should('not.exist') `can someone help me pls?`

```
`/// \<reference types="cypress" /\>
 describe('Frontend tasks', ()=\>{
it('First Task',()=\>{
cy.visit('https://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/alert.php#load_box')
cy.contains('Input Alert').click()
cy.get('#example-1-tab-2')
.should('be.visible')
.its('0.contentDocument.body')
.should('not.empty')
.should('not.empty')
.then(cy.wrap)
})
})`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress Iframe Handling - Failure to interact with Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010936/cypress-iframe-handling-failure-to-interact-with-button)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress e2e testing: How to access new tab by clicking on "href". I don't have target attribute to remove and test on new opened tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994758/cypress-e2e-testing-how-to-access-new-tab-by-clicking-on-href-i-dont-have-t)

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of small typos in your test code, but I think if you attempt with the following example instead, you might achieve what you want to do.

```js
cy.get('iframe.demo-frame:eq(1)')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .should('not.empty')
```

The `<iframe>` elements have a class of `.demo-frame` and you want the second one on the page.